# Write to clipboard with custom mime type in node js

Tags: node.js, applescript

Is it possible to set the cipboard using a cusom mime type with NodeJS?

I trying to set some text in the clipboard with a mime type of "dyn.ah62d4rv4gk8zuxnxnq" so it can be pasted onto another application.

I'm on mac - so if someone has an Applescript/osascript solution that'll work too :)

Comment: There is `pbcopy` (`man pbcopy`) but that doesn’t allow you to set the data’s type. AFAIK the only way to do that is by using `NSPasteboard` via an [objc bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objc).

Comment: Oh boy - that's getting a bit extreme. I might try to find another way

Comment: I'm guessing you're either pasting it into FileMaker or copying it from FileMaker and pasting it into another application.  Which one are you doing ?